# Animation on Visiblity change : property was already registered by 'FrameworkElement'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, frameworkelement

I'm using this code to set an animation on visibility change.

```
public class VisibilityAnimation : DependencyObject
{
    public enum AnimationType
    {
        None,
        Fade
    }

    private const int AnimationDuration = 1000;

    private static readonly Dictionary<FrameworkElement, bool> _hookedElements =
        new Dictionary<FrameworkElement, bool>();

    public static AnimationType GetAnimationType(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (AnimationType)obj.GetValue(AnimationTypeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAnimationType(DependencyObject obj, AnimationType value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AnimationTypeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimationTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AnimationType",
            typeof(AnimationType),
            typeof(VisibilityAnimation),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(AnimationType.None,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAnimationTypePropertyChanged)));
    private static void OnAnimationTypePropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;

        if (frameworkElement == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If AnimationType is set to True on this framework element, 
        if (GetAnimationType(frameworkElement) != AnimationType.None)
        {
            // Add this framework element to hooked list
            HookVisibilityChanges(frameworkElement);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, remove it from the hooked list
            UnHookVisibilityChanges(frameworkElement);
        }
    }
    private static void HookVisibilityChanges(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        _hookedElements.Add(frameworkElement, false);
    }
    private static void UnHookVisibilityChanges(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        if (_hookedElements.ContainsKey(frameworkElement))
        {
            _hookedElements.Remove(frameworkElement);
        }
    }
    static VisibilityAnimation()
    {
        // Here we "register" on Visibility property "before change" event
        UIElement.VisibilityProperty.AddOwner(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                Visibility.Visible,
                VisibilityChanged,
                CoerceVisibility));

    }
    private static void VisibilityChanged(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ignore
    }
    private static object CoerceVisibility(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        object baseValue)
    {
        // Make sure object is a framework element
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement == null)
        {
            return baseValue;
        }

        // Cast to type safe value
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)baseValue;

        // If Visibility value hasn't change, do nothing.
        // This can happen if the Visibility property is set using data binding 
        // and the binding source has changed but the new visibility value 
        // hasn't changed.
        if (visibility == frameworkElement.Visibility || visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) //Aggiungo da cri..x fare l'effetto solo sul fade in
        {
            return baseValue;
        }

        // If element is not hooked by our attached property, stop here
        if (!IsHookedElement(frameworkElement))
        {
            return baseValue;
        }

        // Update animation flag
        // If animation already started, don't restart it (otherwise, infinite loop)
        if (UpdateAnimationStartedFlag(frameworkElement))
        {
            return baseValue;
        }

        // If we get here, it means we have to start fade in or fade out animation. 
        // In any case return value of this method will be Visibility.Visible, 
        // to allow the animation.
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(AnimationDuration))
        };

        // When animation completes, set the visibility value to the requested 
        // value (baseValue)
        doubleAnimation.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                // In case we change into Visibility.Visible, the correct value 
                // is already set, so just update the animation started flag
                UpdateAnimationStartedFlag(frameworkElement);
            }
            else
            {
                // This will trigger value coercion again 
                // but UpdateAnimationStartedFlag() function will reture true 
                // this time, thus animation will not be triggered. 
                if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(frameworkElement,
                    UIElement.VisibilityProperty))
                {
                    // Set visiblity using bounded value
                    Binding bindingValue =
                        BindingOperations.GetBinding(frameworkElement,
                            UIElement.VisibilityProperty);
                    BindingOperations.SetBinding(frameworkElement,
                        UIElement.VisibilityProperty, bindingValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    // No binding, just assign the value
                    frameworkElement.Visibility = visibility;
                }
            }
        };

        if (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed || visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
        {
            // Fade out by animating opacity
            doubleAnimation.From = 1.0;
            doubleAnimation.To = 0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Fade in by animating opacity
            doubleAnimation.From = 0.0;
            doubleAnimation.To = 1.0;
        }

        // Start animation
        frameworkElement.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);

        // Make sure the element remains visible during the animation
        // The original requested value will be set in the completed event of 
        // the animation
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    private static bool IsHookedElement(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        return _hookedElements.ContainsKey(frameworkElement);
    }
    private static bool UpdateAnimationStartedFlag(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        bool animationStarted = (bool)_hookedElements[frameworkElement];
        _hookedElements[frameworkElement] = !animationStarted;

        return animationStarted;
    }
```

In the xaml I need to set: `VisibilityAnimation.AnimationType="Fade"`

The animation works fine, but the problem is that I have the error in the title.

How can I fix this?

Stack Overflow wants more details to insert this code, but it's all.. write this phrase hoping I can insert it.

Comment: Isn't dispatcher timer gonna work in this? cause I have used that in Windows Mobile 8. And use opacity (for visibility) to create your own animation.

Comment: Are to looking for a fade in/out based on visibility changed? or concern is more then that?

Comment: i want understand how fix this error, but the main thing i want do is the fade in effect.. if you have an alternative that i can use i appreciate it

Comment: are you limited to use only `Visibility`? is that ok with you to use another trigger eg `FadeHelper.Visibility`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) OverrideMetadata (related to AddOwner) should only be called from the static constructor of the type that has it's property Metadata overridden. I'm assuming this rule is the same for **AddOwner** method of a Dependency Property.

By the way do you really need such an application wide hook? Based on the code you have, looks like what you are really looking for is a Visibility change notification for the FrameworkElement your attached property is assigned to. You can achieve this the following way.
**DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement)).AddValueChange(frameworkElement, callback)**

But since what you are looking for is a app wide hook to Visibility cores value callback for FrameworkElements, you could do something like this

```
    static VisibilityAnimation()
    {
        // Here we "register" on Visibility property "before change" event
        var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement));
        desc.DesignerCoerceValueCallback += CoerceVisibility;
```

By the way there is a high possibility that FrameworkElements that this property is hooked on to will not get garbage collected since they are heled up in _hookedElements dictionary until AnimationType Property changes to AnimationType.None.

Comment: it work! thanks! p.s. from your words i understand that this strategy is not very good? is there an alternative to put an effect fade in on visibility change?

Comment: The issue is this: does UnHookVisibilityChanges(frameworkElement); ever gets called in practice? If not is it possible for you to make sure it will get called? If the answer to both questions is no, then you may have to use a WeakDictionary like this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicholg/archive/2006/06/04/617466.aspx to avert memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

In your static constructor, change the owner type to your `VisibilityAnimation` class

```
static VisibilityAnimation()
{
    // Here we "register" on Visibility property "before change" event
    UIElement.VisibilityProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(VisibilityAnimation),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            Visibility.Visible,
            VisibilityChanged,
            CoerceVisibility));

}
```

Comment: did but don't work. Now in xaml i have an error about that AnimationType need to derived from DependenceObject

Comment: @Atomico I'm not getting any errors, maybe you could supply some `XAML` or code to show how you are using the `VisibilityAnimation`.

Comment: the xaml code that receive the error is the one i post in first thread: VisibilityAnimation.AnimationType="Fade"

Comment: @Atomico Yes, but that doesn't really give any insight in how you're exactly using it. Are you specifying the namespace, what's the exact error message, etc? Because this works for me: <Grid local:VisibilityAnimation.AnimationType="Fade" Background="Red" />

Comment: Well, you see the animation? it don't give any error now, but no animation show.

Comment: @Atomico Yes, I do see the animation if I toggle the visibility of the grid between visible and hidden

Comment: Can you paste the code you use to change visibility pls

Comment: @Atomico <Grid>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chk" />
        <Grid Background="Red" local:VisibilityAnimation.AnimationType="Fade" Margin="0,30,0,0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=chk, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"/></Grid>. conv is a BooleanToVisibilityConverter

Comment: I change visibility from code-behind(button event).. this change something?

Comment: No, still works for me when I toggle visibility in a button click eventhandler.